# Visual studio (2015) tools for Apache Cordova Update 1 failed to install

Tags: cordova, installation, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install the update 1 of Apache Cordova. But it instantly comes back with the following error message:

> The selected Visual Studio item 'Visual Studio Tools For Apache
>   Cordova Update 1' failed to install. Check the %TEMP% directory for VS
>   install logs.

When I go to that directory, I don't see any log related to this install. Even when sorting everything on date descending, there is no log related to this install.

This update can't be found on the microsoft site either as a separate download or something.

Anyone else bumped into this error?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Yes but I don't recall how. I think I installed the newest update which might have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
After talking to the support team the following helped:

1. Go to Add/Remove Programs and select VS2015 and select change.
2. (*Optional): If you have what I had where it told me that it isn't installed just reinstall VS 2015 and goto step 3
3. Choose "Apache Cordova 4"(that is the update version when writing this answer. Of course you should select the version at the time you read this).
4. Finish the installation

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your trouble. Could you try going to add / remove programs and uninstalling "Tools for Apache Cordova", and then retrying? Hopefully that works.

If it doesn't, my team would like to help. Please email us at vscordovatools@microsoft.com so we can work with you to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I just did what you suggested but the update 1 for Apache Cordova disappeared from the notification window. I'll compose a mail later today as it's 1 AM now.